# How to set the language of iCloud calendar reminder emails?

Tags: icloud, email, calendar, internationalization

Ever since iCloud Calendar became publicly available I have used it to arrange my schedule. I meet with people from other countries on a regular basis and I'd like the Calendar reminder emails I send to people when setting up a meeting to be in English. Unfortunately, that's not the case. iCloud always sends my meeting invites in my native language (the country my AppleID is assigned to).

It seems that iCloud is ignoring my OS and iCloud web interface language choice, as they're both set to English.

Is there a way to change the default language of Calendar reminders somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

First visit [Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com/). Then click Mange your Apple ID, middle on the right of the page:

[image]

Login and then click Language and Contact Preferences.

[image]

Here you can select English US or English UK.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem, and i finally solved it,

Go to appleid.apple.com and set the preferred language for your account.